# Intel XDK disable rotation

Tags: android, html, apk, intel, intel-xdk

I made a simple application in Intel XDK.
When I was testing the application I noticed that they enabled the accelerometer.

For this application it's needed to have only 1 position.
How can I disable the accelerometer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its not accelerometer that is causing, its the device orientation that needs to fixed.

Call this API to fix the orientation: `intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation(ORIENTATION);` after `intel.xdk.device.ready` has fired.

Full documentation is [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493051)

**Portrait**: `intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");`

**Landscape**: `intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("landscape");`

**Both**: `intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("any");`

Below is sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XDK</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />

    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>

    <script>
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);               
function onDeviceReady(){
    // set orientation
    intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('landscape');
//    intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('portrait');
//    intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('any');

    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();   
}        
    </script>
    <style>
        body {font-family:arial;background-color:white}
    </style>    
</head>
<body> 
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Locked to Landscape</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is possible do it the way next:

1. Go the project properties.
2. Build Settings
3. Orientation

You select, landscape or portrait.
If you emule the project, you see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

use the `setRotateOrientation`-Method:

To lock the device in portrait mode, use:

```
intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");
```

Works on Android as well as iOS.

See: [Documentation](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493051)

Answer (score 0):

Easier is to go to Build Settings -> Your Platform -> Orientation. That very fast and simple.